# What exactly happens when you download multiple files from firefox?

Tags: multithreading, firefox, multiprocessing

I'm trying to understand what happens when you download multiple files from Firefox at the same time. Is it using multithreading or multiprocessing? Assuming it's using multithreading, how many threads is it using? How can I figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

One way to figure it out is to look at the source.

Also, a script like this might give you a good starting point:

```
while ps x | grep -i firefox | wc; do sleep 1; done
```

which prints something like this:

```
  16     392    6607
  16     392    6607
  16     392    6607
```

...

then start downloading a file that takes more than a few seconds and see how many new processes it starts.
Depending upon your OS, you might want to consult the man page for ps to figure out how to report threads as well as processes. You might need a little more smarts than grep.

If you need to dive deeper, but don't want to go into the source, most OSes have some mechanism to view a trace of the system calls a program makes.  This could be truss, strace, dtrace, ...

There is also a possibility that it uses no threads or processes to download files; it merely relies on select (man 2 select).

Happy hunting.